# Docker Build failing when dockerizing rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm dockerizing a rails application, when trying to build the docker image from the docker file which I've written, rails installation is failing.

This is the Dockerfile. I've made sure the ruby, rails, and bundler versions on my laptop and in the Dockerfile are the same.

My docker version is `Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88`

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV RUBY_MAJOR="2.6" \
    RUBY_VERSION="2.6.3" \
    RUBYGEMS_VERSION="3.0.8" \
    BUNDLER_VERSION="1.17.3" \
    RAILS_VERSION="5.2.1" \
    RAILS_ENV="production" \
    GEM_HOME="/usr/local/bundle"
ENV BUNDLE_PATH="$GEM_HOME" \
    BUNDLE_BIN="$GEM_HOME/bin" \
    BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING=1 \
    BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG="$GEM_HOME"

ENV PATH="$BUNDLE_BIN:$GEM_HOME/bin:$GEM_HOME/gems/bin:$PATH"

USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo
RUN echo "%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
    addgroup --gid 1024 stars && \
    useradd -G stars,sudo -d /home/user --shell /bin/bash -m user
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/etc \
    && echo 'install: --no-document' >> /usr/local/etc/gemrc \
    && echo 'update: --no-document' >> /usr/local/etc/gemrc

USER user
RUN sudo apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends vim make gcc zlib1g-dev autoconf build-essential libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev \
    curl htop unzip mc openssh-server openssl bison libgdbm-dev ruby git libmysqlclient-dev tzdata mysql-client
    
RUN sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && sudo curl -fSL -o ruby.tar.gz "http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/$RUBY_MAJOR/ruby-$RUBY_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && sudo mkdir -p /usr/src/ruby \
    && sudo tar -xzf ruby.tar.gz -C /usr/src/ruby --strip-components=1 \
    && sudo rm ruby.tar.gz

USER root
RUN cd /usr/src/ruby \
    && { sudo echo '#define ENABLE_PATH_CHECK 0'; echo; cat file.c; } > file.c.new && mv file.c.new file.c \
    && autoconf \
    && ./configure --disable-install-doc

USER user
RUN cd /usr/src/ruby \
    && sudo make -j"$(nproc)" \
    && sudo make install \
    && sudo gem update --system $RUBYGEMS_VERSION \
    && sudo rm -r /usr/src/ruby
RUN sudo gem install bundler --version "$BUNDLER_VERSION"

RUN sudo mkdir -p "$GEM_HOME" "$BUNDLE_BIN" \
    && sudo chmod 777 "$GEM_HOME" "$BUNDLE_BIN" \
    && sudo gem install rails --version "$RAILS_VERSION"
RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 ~/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ARG ssh_pub_key
ARG ssh_prv_key
RUN echo "$ssh_pub_key" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    echo "$ssh_prv_key" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
USER root
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
USER user
WORKDIR /data
RUN sudo mkdir /data/checklist
WORKDIR /data/checklist
ADD Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN sudo chown -R user /data/checklist
RUN bundle install
ADD . .
RUN sudo chown -R user /data/checklist
EXPOSE 3001
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES true
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
RUN chmod +x ./config/docker/prepare-db.sh && sh ./config/docker/prepare-db.sh

CMD ["sh", "./config/docker/startup.sh"]
```

Error is

```
#13 90.14 ERROR:  Error installing rails:
#13 90.14   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
#13 90.14 
#13 90.14     current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10/ext/mimemagic
#13 90.14 /usr/local/bin/ruby -rrubygems /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR\=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/mimemagic-0.3.10 RUBYLIBDIR\=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/mimemagic-0.3.10
#13 90.14 rake aborted!
#13 90.14 Could not find MIME type database in the following locations: ["/usr/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/homebrew/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/opt/local/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml", "/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml"]
#13 90.14 
#13 90.14 Ensure you have either installed the shared-mime-info package for your distribution, or
#13 90.14 obtain a version of freedesktop.org.xml and set FREEDESKTOP_MIME_TYPES_PATH to the location
#13 90.14 of that file.
#13 90.14 
#13 90.14 This gem might be installed as a dependency of some bigger package, such as rails, activestorage,
#13 90.14 axlsx or cucumber. While most of these packages use the functionality of this gem, some gems have
#13 90.14 included this gem by accident. Set USE_FREEDESKTOP_PLACEHOLDER=true if you are certain that you
#13 90.14 do not need this gem, and wish to skip the inclusion of freedesktop.org.xml.
#13 90.14 
#13 90.14 The FREEDESKTOP_PLACEHOLDER option is meant as a transitional feature, and will be deprecated in
#13 90.14 the next release.
#13 90.14 
#13 90.14 Tasks: TOP => default
#13 90.14 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
#13 90.14 
#13 90.14 rake failed, exit code 1
#13 90.14 
#13 90.14 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mimemagic-0.3.10 for inspection.
#13 90.14 Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/mimemagic-0.3.10/gem_make.out
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c sudo mkdir -p "$GEM_HOME" "$BUNDLE_BIN"     && sudo chmod 777 "$GEM_HOME" "$BUNDLE_BIN"     && sudo gem install rails --version "$RAILS_VERSION"]: exit code: 1
```

I'm stuck here not able to proceed further. Please help me out.

Comment: This is likely related to the mime type database change in rails that happened last month. Either add freedesktop.org.xml to your docker build or upgrade to Rails 5.2.5 -- which should remedy the issue.

Comment: can I directly change the rails version in the gemfile and give bundle install, will that work? or do you suggest any other way to upgrade the rails version @dbugger

Comment: Yes, change it in the gem file and update your ENV RAILS_VERSION to keep confusion to a minimum.